# How do i assign a click event to every circle in a canvas Api using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas

I have tried everything to solve this but I can't seem to figure it out. Is there a straightforward way of clicking on the circles or do I have to calculate the area of the circles relative to the canvas size? The general idea is to simulate a 2d LED display. When clicked it turns off and on. The idea is to create emoji patterns with the LEDs.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { color: "red",blur:20, ledOn: true };
    this.elements = [];
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateCanvas();
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.updateCanvas();
  }

  updateCanvas = () => {
    const canvas = this.refs.canvas;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = this.state.color;
    ctx.shadowBlur = this.state.blur;
    ctx.shadowColor = this.state.color;
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(12.5 + j * 25, 12.5 + i * 25, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        ctx.fill();
      }
    }
  };
```

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6aWz.png)

Comment: If you use canvas, yea you need to translate the xy coordinate of the click to the item in your grid array. You could use divs or svgs and add an `onClick` which would be simpler.

Comment: You could also use something like `pixi.js` which comes with helpers for interactivity

Comment: You could use css instead of canvas for this. Do you need to use canvas?

Comment: @azium thanks for the ideas. I like the idea of svgs, could you guide me a little or suggest a link i use could use. Thanks.

Comment: @tudor.gergely yes the task specifically requires canvas.

Comment: @dominictraviskudix I meant use svgs instead of canvas.. if you're using canvas you'll need to write your own targeting function or use a canvas lib that already has it like pixi or phaser